# curl suppress error on form submit

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have a form that asks for a email and city.  The city select also redirects the page to a /examplecity part of the site.  The email is then process and a conformation is sent to the user.  If the user exists already the page redirects to the error page.

Any idea how to suppress the error page and just move on?  I have tried a few curl options but no results.

Here is my code.

```
//form
 $Curl_Session = curl_init('http://alist-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=08fd07d8be6c7c671&id=960c347');
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, TRUE);
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "&group=$group&MERGE0=$email");
 //
 //curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
 curl_close ($Curl_Session);
 setcookie("city", $city, time()+604800); // cookie expires in 7 days. 
header("Location: http://site.ca/".$city.""); 
exit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the http://www.alist.com/ page redirects to an error page if the user doesn't exist, and you want it to go straight to the http://site.ca/ page?

Try adding this:

```
curl_setopt($Curl_Session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
```

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER causes it to return a string of the result rather than a direct output to the browser.  You could actually capture and parse it to determine if there was an error page to display your own error to the user or handle it in some fashion.  Oh, you can also select my answer as the solution.